# AngularFire how I can update all values

Tags: firebase, angularfire

**How I can to put on the table all values contabilidad (pago) to 0, all the same time not one by one?**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase recently introduced the ability to [update multiple locations with one `update()` call](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html).

```
ref.child('contabilidad').once('value', function(snapshot) {
  var updates = {};
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    updates[child.key()+'/pago'] = 0;
  });
  ref.child('contabilidad').update(updates);
});
```

Also see [this blog post on how to use this feature for atomic client-side fan-out](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but something more, how can i sum the  total of pago